# IBM Watson integration with Twilio via Whatsapp

Tags: node.js, twilio, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to integrate IBM Watson bot with twilio, whatsapp using IBM cloud functions using Nodejs. I followed the following to come up with this code https://github.com/ChaitanyaGhantasala/Whatsapp/blob/master/app.js
Please find below the Code:

```
// Import Modules
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()
var AssistantV1 = require('ibm-watson/assistant/v1');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');


// Twilio Credentials

var accountSid = '';
var authToken = '';
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ entended: false }));
var env= require('dotenv').config()


// Watson Credentials
var assistant = new AssistantV1({
version: '2018-09-20',
authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
apikey: '',
}),
url: '',
});

var context1 = {};
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
})
// API

app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
console.log("Request Object");
var From = req.body.From;
console.log(From);
assistant.message({
skill_id: '',
input: { 'text': req.body.Body },
context: context1
}, function (err, response) {
if (err)
console.log('error:', err);
else {
context1 = response.context;
var msg = response.output.text[0];
console.log("message", msg);
client.messages
.create({
body: msg,
from:'whatsapp:+14155238886',
to: 'From',
}).then(message = console.log(msg))
.done();

}
})
});

//PORT Listen
app.listen(process.env.PORT||8000, function () {
console.log("Server is running at 8000");
});
```

This line shows an error

```
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');
```

Also, i have no idea how the integration work
Can you please help me with any resources?
This does not work with me,

Comment: What's your question? Any specific problem?

Comment: Yes, The integration does not work, i have no idea how can i make it happen

Comment: What is the error, what are the steps you performed? How do you run the code? Have you installed all needed modules / packages?

Comment: the Authenticator line, i run it using Node, yes i install all modules

Comment: See here for the SDK with links to docs on how to use https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

I am basing this answer on you not being able to format code. The code you show is basic / simple, yet you have made it undecipherable by not formatting it.

You say your error is on the line:

```
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');
```

This is a simple import of a pre-requisite module, which suggests that you have not imported the module `ibm-watson`, however, if that were the case then the  line above it should also fail.

```
var AssistantV1 = require('ibm-watson/assistant/v1');
```

In which case you are hitting a version problem, either in your version of Node.js that is not recognising the `const` format, or in the version of `ibm-watson` that is not exporting `ibm-watson/auth`.

Based on your lack of basic code formatting, I am guessing that it is the version of Node.js. The current version of `ibm-watson` : 5.6.0 requires `"node": ">=10.0.0"`.